# RemoteTokenService for multiple client application

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, oauth2client

How can I use RemoteTokenService for more than one client application (with different client_id and secret )?

UPDATE

```
public ResourceServerTokenServices tokenService() {
        RemoteTokenServices tokenServices = new RemoteTokenServices();

        tokenServices.setClientId("sample_test_client_app_auth_code");
        tokenServices.setClientSecret("secret");
        tokenServices.setCheckTokenEndpointUrl("http://localhost:8080/oauth/check_token");

        return tokenServices;
    }
```

That's how we configure instance of RemoteTokenService. and inject it to the OAuth2AuthenticationManager for separate Resource server and auth server. Is it correct?

so when some other client has to access this resource how can I configure RemoteTokenService for both of this client.can you provide some light on this. and tell me if I am wrong on something.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: @DaveSyer question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client id in the `RemoteTokenServices` is not the client that is consuming the resource, it's the client associated with the resource itself (solely for the purpose of authentication of the /check_token endpoint). So once you have it working you can hit that resource from as many clients as you like.

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly, a resource server can also be a client under the oAuth paradigm?

Comment: The spec doesn't mention it, so it doesn't preclude it. For the sake of clarity, the check_token endpoint is not part of the spec.

Comment: Hi @DaveSyer ,How can I get info of the `many clients`  in the resource server?